# Are two functions (one with php) possible with "onclick"?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, function

I have the following script which shall fire two functions at the same time. One function shall call/load a php file (index.php to query a mysql) and the other shall run a javascript. Is this even possible? Thanks for your help in advance.

```
$.get("index.php", {id : searchform, name : tweetfinder}, function() {
// Here you can do the other operations
onclick("submit");
$('searchform').submit();
});
</script>
<form id="searchform" name="tweetfinder">
<div class="input-append">
<input class="span3" autofocus="autofocus">
<button class="btn btn-primary">Do Stuff!</button>
</div></form>
```

How about this approach (enter mysql query as a function?):

```
function showstuff(){
<?php
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `xxx` WHERE `xxx` = '$xxx' ORDER BY `rank` DESC")or die(mysql_error());
while($ass = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
$viewer = $ass['playername'];
echo "<a href=\"index.php?viewuser=".$viewer."\">".$viewer."</a> , ";
};
```

Comment: No you cannot call PHP function with javascript, you need to learn the difference between client and server side scripting

Comment: Loading a new URL *and* submitting a form contradict each other. Please explain what you're trying to achieve with that.

Comment: It depends on your definition of simultaneously...

Comment: Thanks everyone. I want to access a database and execute a javascript at the same time. Mmmm its harder than I thought as a noob to get this right. So I guess back to school:) @bfavaretto did this short answer help?

Comment: I'm still unsure what exactly you are trying to do. But if the ajax solution suggested below doesn't work, you can edit your question to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to your AJAX (jQuery) then I would like to suggest. What you do, using the AJAX call get the data of the other file and at its callback do the other operations.

```
$.get("index.php", {id : 5, name : MyName}, function() {
  // Here you can do the other operations
  alert('Do more things');
  $('formID').submit();
});
```

For more details Refer [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this immediately.

Comment: After 2 hours of trying I could not get it right. I edited to code in the question to the current one...Still a long way to go for me...